# run Grunt.js with Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gruntjs

I've set up a Gruntfile with mocha testing and JSlint. This works fine if i just run grunt form the terminal.

I want to run grunt from Jenkins!

I set up a new job -> and made built to a shell script and included:

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt
```

Once I run the job the terminal output of Jenkins says:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8550584576040162032.sh
+ /usr/local/bin/grunt
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

it seems it cant fine node binary!?! but node is installed and runs fine in the terminal!

All my binaries (mocha, grunt, node) are in /usr/local/bin/

Does anyone know what the issue is? Or maybe someone has a link to set up grunt.js with jenkins?

Somebody got something?

Thx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is happening because Jenkins will be running as a different user which probably doesn't have `/usr/local/bin` in its `$PATH`.

In your shell script make sure `/usr/local/bin` is being added to your `$PATH`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
# This will also mean you can call 'grunt' rather than '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
grunt
```

This has the added benefit of calling any programs you've installed in `/usr/local/bin` over anything in `/usr/bin`. If you don't want this behavior, simply append instead of prepend:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
# This will also mean you can call 'grunt' rather than '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
grunt
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm not familiar with Jenkins but I had same issue when I wanted to integrate GruntJS with XCode custom build step or within TeamCity deployment process.

I fixed my problem by adding /usr/local/bin/ to the PATH within my shell script before running  grunt or node. Something like:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
grunt
```

I hope  this helps you as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can allow setup everything from jenkins :

### Install Jenkins Plugins

- Git Plugin - *for git*
- Git Client Plugin - *for git*
- Git Parameter Plugin - *for git tags*
- GitHub API Plugin - *for github*
- NodeJS Plugin - *integration for common javascript tools NodeJS & npm*

### Git / Ant / Maven / NodeJS Installations

- Goto SERVER/jenkins/configure

Git

- Git -> Git installations -> Add Git -> JGit
- Git plugin -> Global Config user.name Value = "Anthony Mckale", Global Config user.email Value = "anthony.mckale@bskyb.com"

NodeJS

- NodeJS- > NodeJS installations -> Add NodeJS -> Name = "NodeJS 0.11.10", tick "Install automatically", select "Install from nodejs.org", add "grunt-cli" to globally installed packages

### TADA

and hopefully git/nodejs and grunt will be available to you